# Grunt "watch.sass.files" missing

Tags: terminal, sass, gruntjs, watch

Beginning with Grunt, which I love but cannot make it work as I get continously an error with my sass implementation. I get the following alerts:

```
Danis-MacBook-Pro:020 DanielRamirez$ grunt
Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File "js/build/production.js" created.

Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
File js/build/production.min.js created.
>> No "sass" targets found.
Warning: Task "sass" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Danis-MacBook-Pro:020 DanielRamirez$
```

If I `--force` I get the following:

```
Danis-MacBook-Pro:020 DanielRamirez$ grunt
Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File "js/build/production.js" created.

Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
File js/build/production.min.js created.
>> No "sass" targets found.
Warning: Task "sass" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Danis-MacBook-Pro:020 DanielRamirez$
```

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here.

        // Concatonate various files into one
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/vendor/*.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/plugin.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/global.js'  // This specific file
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            }
        },

        // Creates a minified version of the javascript files of the project
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: ['js/vendor/*.js', 'js/plugin.js', 'js/global.js'],
                dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
            }
        },

         // Minifies automatically the images of the project
        // imagemin: {
        //     dynamic: {
        //         files: [{
        //             expand: true,
        //             cwd: 'images/',
        //             src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        //             dest: 'images/build/'
        //         }]
        //     }
        // },

        // Watches for changes done on the project and builds the commands if neccesary
        watch: {

             options: {
                livereload: true,
            },

            scripts: {
                files: ['js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                },
            },

            sass: {
                dist: {
                    options: {
                        style: 'compressed'
                    },
                    files: {
                        'css/build/style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
                    }
                }
            },

            css: {
                files: ['css/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'sass', 'compass', 'watch']);

};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you've done is put the entire Sass configuration inside the watch config. Grunt does not work this way. Instead, change your config to something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here.

        // Concatonate various files into one
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/vendor/*.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/plugin.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                    'js/global.js'  // This specific file
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            }
        },

        // Creates a minified version of the javascript files of the project
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: ['js/vendor/*.js', 'js/plugin.js', 'js/global.js'],
                dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
            }
        },
        // Compile sass to css
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/build/style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },

         // Minifies automatically the images of the project
        // imagemin: {
        //     dynamic: {
        //         files: [{
        //             expand: true,
        //             cwd: 'images/',
        //             src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        //             dest: 'images/build/'
        //         }]
        //     }
        // },

        // Watches for changes done on the project and builds the commands if neccesary
        watch: {

             options: {
                livereload: true,
            },

            scripts: {
                files: ['js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                },
            },

            css: {
                files: ['css/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'sass', 'compass', 'watch']);

};
```

Comment: Hey! It worked! You were write. It compiles but I'm getting an error: Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
              Load paths:
                /Users/DanielRamirez/Sites/020
                /Users/DanielRamirez/Sites/020/sass
        on line 86 of sass/_base.scss
        from line 7 of sass/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Comment: You'll want the compass option: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#compass

Comment: How do you implement this in the Gruntfile.js? Ins't this already added with the grunt-contrib-compass I have in the example above? Or is it a different thing? sorry for the confusion

Comment: I'd say use either one, but be consistent; don't use both! You could always change the `sass` target to `compass` instead. The compass and sass plugins don't know about each other so either use compass option with sass, or just use the compass plugin. I have a feeling that the compass plugin is going to be better if you're working a lot with that toolkit.

Comment: I thought that the SASS was necessary to have the functionalities of SASS while you edit. Therefore, Compass plugin will create also the compressed style file? Thank you for the help... really helping.

Comment: Either sass or compass is fine for that, you don't need both. In production you may want to make use of something like `grunt-contrib-cssmin` to minify the compass output. :-)